# Swift UI @ObservedObject not working, found weird behaviour when implementing another protocol

Tags: swift, swiftui, protocols

following this guide ["Stanford university"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SIYdYpPXil4&list=PLpGHT1n4-mAtTj9oywMWoBx0dCGd51_yG&index=13) I implemented a model(struct) named MemoryGame with a second struct inside named card ( implementing Identifiable ) with viewModel named EmojiMemoryGame(class) witch holds the model(MemoryGame) with a wrapper "@Published". in the contentView I have the viewModel(EmojiMemoryGame) with "@ObservedObject" wrapper.

This works fine, when the data changed the view get notified and updates, But I found 1 problem I don't understand, when the card struct ( the one in MemoryGame struct ) witch implements "Identifiable" implement another protocol ( i tried Equatable and Comparable ) the UI not getting updated ( I checked that the data is changing ). when implementing Equatable with the "func ==" the UI not updating at all, it become weirder when I remove the Equatable name from the struct declaration but I leave the "func ==" in there, its work.

I tried the same with Comparable and implemented the funcs "<" and "==", same thing, the @ObservedObject not working but if I remove the Comparable from the struct declaration its works.

*side question: when I removed Equatable from the struct but left the "==" func inside its still gave me the option to compare both object like it still implements Equatable. is this normal ?

I new to this and still don't know how to debug the objectWillChange.send() ( I tried but so far I failed I think )

the code is below

this is the model MemoryGame, I commented out the protocols that brake the functionality

```
import Foundation


  struct MemoryGame<CardContent> {

var cards : [Card]



mutating func choose(card : Card) {
    cards[index].isFaceUp = !cards[index].isFaceUp
   
}

struct Card : Identifiable /* , Equatable , Comparable */  {
    //        static func < (lhs: MemoryGame<CardContent>.Card, rhs: MemoryGame<CardContent>.Card) -> Bool {
    //            lhs.id < rhs.id
    //        }
    //
    //        static func == (lhs: MemoryGame<CardContent>.Card, rhs: MemoryGame<CardContent>.Card) -> Bool {
    //            lhs.id == rhs.id
    //        }
    //
    static func == (lhs: Card, rhs: Card) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
    
    var isFaceUp : Bool = true
    var isMatched : Bool = false
    var content : CardContent
    var id : Int
}
```

}

this is the viewModel EmojiMemoryGame

```
import SwiftUI


    class EmojiMemoryGame : ObservableObject {

typealias CoreGame = MemoryGame<String>

@Published private var model : CoreGame = EmojiMemoryGame.createMemoryGame()

func choose(card:CoreGame.Card) {
    model.choose(card: card)
}
```

}

and this is the contentVIew

```
import SwiftUI

 struct EmojiMemoryGameView: View {

@ObservedObject var viewModel : EmojiMemoryGame

var body: some View {
    HStack {
        ForEach(viewModel.cards) { card in
            CardView(card: card).onTapGesture {
                self.viewModel.choose(card: card)
            }
        }
    }
    .padding()
    .foregroundColor(.orange)
}
}

 struct CardView : View {

var card : MemoryGame<String>.Card

var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        if card.isFaceUp {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10.0).fill().foregroundColor(.white)
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10.0).stroke(lineWidth: 3.0)
            Text(card.content)
                .font(.system(size: 200))
                .minimumScaleFactor(0.1)
                .lineLimit(1)
                
                
        } else {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10.0).fill()
        }
        
    }.aspectRatio(CGSize(width: 20, height: 30), contentMode: .fit)
 }
 }



struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
static var previews: some View {
    EmojiMemoryGameView(viewModel: EmojiMemoryGame())
}
```

}

Comment: Make some short reproducible standalone demo.

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to include all relevant code in the form of a [mcve] in order to make the question on-topic.

Comment: I removed unnecessary code, hope it make it better

Comment: I got the same error.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue, I solved it just by adding extra parameters for checking to make sure your object is equal.

```
static func == (lhs: MemoryGame<CardContent>.Card, rhs: MemoryGame<CardContent>.Card) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id && lhs.isFaceUp == rhs.isFaceUp && lhs.isMatched == rhs.isMatched
    }
```

The reason for the issue was that iOS compares old object(lhs) state with new object(lhs) state was returning true for both both the states. It should return true only for new states.

[image]

As you can see from the console.... equality operator is called at multiple times.. and in your case it was returning true for each time.. That is why iOS was unable to distinguish between changed object and old object and so it didn't publish the notification